# list comprehension returning 3 values

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I would like to make a list comprehension, since using for loop will make the program slow so I wish to convert it to list comprehensions. However, I wanted it to return 3 values mainly the i, ii and word. I tried my method but i received errors like:

Errors:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

Brief about my codes type:

```
words: Is a list[List[string]] # [["I","have","something","to","buy"]]
word: is a word in string type
```

Code:

```
i, ii, word = [[i, ii, word] for i, w in enumerate(words) for ii, ww in
                     enumerate(w) for wwd in ww if word == wwd]
```

Expected output:

For example, i list will contain the index for words, ii list will contain the index for w, while word is just list of strings that are similar to wwd.

```
i = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ~] # this index should be relevant to the matching of wwd == word
ii = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ~] # this index should be relevant to the matching of wwd == word
word = ["I", "have", "something"] # this is received when comparing the wwd with word

#Another example: i= 2, ii= 4, word = "have" and then store it to the variables for each matching of word.
```

I am wondering whether is there any shorter version and how can I solve my current issue?

Full Version of my problem:

My code:

```
wordy = [['I', 'have', 'something', 'to', 'buy', 'from', 'home', ',']]
key = {'I': 'We', 'king': 'man', 'value': 'time'}
a = []

def foo(a,b,c): return a,b,c

for ll in key.keys():
    for ii, l in enumerate(wordy):
        for i, word in enumerate(l):
            for wordd in word:
                if ll == wordd:
                    a.append(list(zip([ii, i, ll])))

for x in a:
    i, ii, ll = foo(*x)

print(i,ii,ll)



for ll in key.keys():
    a = [[i, ii, ll]for i, words in enumerate(wordy) for ii, word in enumerate(words) for wordd in word if ll == wordd]
print(a)
for x in a:
    i, ii, ll = foo(*x)
print(i, ii, ll)
```

My current output:

```
0 0 I
[]
0 0 value
```

Expected output:

```
0 0 I
[]
0 0 I
```

I do not know why when use list comprehensions then the value of "ll" become different.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing what you are trying to return. Seems like you want 3 lists at the end? What is each list supposed to contain?

Comment: If you can do it with a for loop, maybe post that here and we can help you make it into a list comprehension. That way, we can understand output better

Comment: You're returning a list, and assign it to 3 variables. Could you please give an example and expected outcome of this?

Comment: may be order of loops wrong

Comment: For example, i list will contain the index for words, ii list will contain the index for w, while word is just list of strings that are similar to wwd.

Comment: Ok, let me reedit my post with expected out

Comment: computer what is [[i, ii, word] for i, w in enumerate(words) for ii, ww in
                     enumerate(w) for wwd in ww if word == wwd] then think how you want to divide it on 3

Comment: I updated and included some brief expected output

Comment: may be give a short example?

Comment: Write it out with a for loop first, then we can help make it a list comprehension

Comment: what is words value in your example

Comment: words: [["I","have","something","to","buy"]]. Is my exmple for words

Comment: Either explain in English what you want the output to look like or write the thing with the for loops you would need to do it right.

Comment: what is  `for 'wwd' in 'I'` how is that supposed to work

Comment: I have uploaded a full version of my problem and my attempt, please check again.

Comment: I believe you are being deceived by this line: `for x in a: i, ii, ll = foo(*x)`
Since there is nothing in the list `a`, this doesn't actually run, so it just uses the last values of `i` `ii` and `ll` from the for loops

Comment: I see. How should I edit my code? If you can help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` with the `*` operator to unpack sequences:

```
i, ii, word = zip(*([a, b, c] for ...))
```

This assumes you can fill in `...` with something that makes sense. Note, in particular, that intermediary list construction isn't required. You can use a generator expression, indicated by the parentheses in place of square brackets.

Technically, your results will be tuples rather than lists. For lists, you can use `map`:

```
i, ii, word = map(list(zip(*...)))
```

Comment: `zip` could be a good idea. However, this code doesn't work. The list-comprehension still needs some work

Comment: @Stephen, Are you sure? `i, ii, word = zip(*(list('abc') for _ in range(5)))` works fine. Isn't this the same?

Comment: Cool!Let me try too.

Comment: `NameError: name 'c' is not defined`

Comment: @Beginner, I can't replicate. As an example, `i, ii, word = zip(*(list('abc') for _ in range(5)))` works and this is roughly what you are doing.

Comment: I agree that is roughly the same, but I think we still need to work on the inside of the list-comprehension

Comment: I tried this code you gave i, ii, word = zip(*([a, b, c] for a, w in enumerate(words) for b, ww in
                     enumerate(w) for wwd in ww if c == wwd))

Comment: But I have included the input data

Comment: Either explain in English what you want the output to look like or write the thing with the for-loops you would need to do it right.

Comment: I have uploaded a full version of my problem and my attempt, please check again.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
wordlist = [['I', 'have', 'something', 'to', 'buy', 'from', 'home', ','],['You', 'king', 'thing', 'and', 'take', 'to', 'work', ',']]
dictionary = {'I': 'We', 'king': 'man', 'value': 'time'}
forloopoutput = []
listcompoutput = []

#For Loop
for key in dictionary.keys():
    for wlist_index, wlist in enumerate(wordlist):
        for word_index, word in enumerate(wlist):
            if key == word:
                forloopoutput.append([wlist_index, word_index, word])

#List comprehension
listcompoutput = [[wlist_index, word_index, word] for word_index, word in enumerate(wlist) for wlist_index, wlist in enumerate(wordlist)for key in dictionary.keys() if key==word]
```

I've changed a few things for clarity:

- I've given the variables clearer (but lengthier) names to make for an easier explanation.
- I'm assuming your "wordy" list is a nested list because in your real life example you are expecting multiple lists, so I've added another list to my example to demonstrate it's use.

Comment: I see. The problem came because my dictionary looping was at outside of list comprehensions. Btw, what about if my wordList = [['I', 'have', 'something', 'to', 'buy', 'from', 'home', ',','king']] and now we have 2 similar words. When this happen, I do not know how to call the values for each word. For example, my output became [[(0,),(0,),('I')],[(1,),(8,),('king')]]. How can I call wlist_index, word_index, word separately? Thank you for helping me re-editing it

Comment: Well you could change the output of the loop, or you could just print the 3rd value of each output list which will always be the value of the word. If that's what you mean?

Comment: New refer to wordList =  [['I', 'have', 'something', 'to', 'buy', 'from', 'home', ',','king']] . For example, we will have an output of [[(0,),(0,),('I')],[(1,),(8,),('king')]]. Then I would like to assign these output to wlist_index, word_index, word. Lets say when we print wlist_index, we will get 0 and 1 given that 0 respect to 'I' and 1 respect to 'king'. Then word_index is 0 respect to 'I' and 8 respect to 'king'. Word = 'I' and 'king' of course. Is there a way to assign values like this? wlist_index = [0,1], word_index = [0,8], word = [''I,'king']?.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. What have you tried, and what isn't working?

Comment: This is what I tried, listcompoutput = [zip([wlist_index, word_index, word]) for word_index, word in enumerate(wlist) for wlist_index, wlist in enumerate(wordlist)for key in dictionary.keys() if key==word]

But since I do not know how to assign the values so I cant make anything improvement. I updated my post as well earlier.